# opencart checking if islogged admin

Tags: admin, opencart2.x

I'm creating a page on admin -the page basically register a new user- and it has accessible without user been logged. 
But somehow opencart sees that user is not logged and redirects to login page.

Does anybody know where opencart checks it? This way I can put an exception.

Many thanks

DM

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered me somewhere else, so I will share it here:

> Straight from the admin/index.php, the check validation is initialized.

```
// Login
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/login/check'));
```